# save button not working in django

Tags: django

Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/new/blog/home_page.html

Using the URLconf defined in school.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
^admin/
^$ [name='home_page']
^about/$ [name='about']
^event/$ [name='event']
^calendar/$ [name='calendar']
^contact/$ [name='contact']
^class_a/$ [name='class_a']
^login/$ [name='login']
^login_submit/$ [name='login_submit']
^class_info/$ [name='class_info']
^Ist_std/$ [name='Ist_std']
^IInd_std/$ [name='IInd_std']
^IIIrd_std/$ [name='IIIrd_std']
^IVth_std/$ [name='IVth_std']
^post/new/$ [name='post_new']
```

The current URL, post/new/blog/home_page.html, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is not matching any of your defined URLs. If you want that page to show anything, you'll need to include a match like:

```
r'^/post/new/blog/home_page$'
```

In url.py and write a view for it to display the wanted html file.

Comment: Above given urls.py doesn't work.I wrote views.py for this urls.py